# SQL JOIN not returning wanted results

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running Oracle 11g but this is a more general SQL question.

So I have the following tables/data -

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_GROUP (
  ID VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT test_group_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
INSERT INTO TEST_GROUP VALUES ('AAA');

CREATE TABLE GROUP_PREFERENCE (
  GROUP_ID VARCHAR2(20),
  ID VARCHAR2(20),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT GROUP_PREF_PK PRIMARY KEY (GROUP_ID, ID, TYPE)
);
INSERT INTO GROUP_PREFERENCE VALUES ('AAA', 'AAA-P1', 'CONFIGURABLE');
INSERT INTO GROUP_PREFERENCE VALUES ('AAA', 'AAA-P2', 'ENABLED');

CREATE TABLE PREFERENCE_ENTRY (
  PREFERENCE_ID VARCHAR2(20),
  PREFERENCE_VALUE VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT PREF_PK PRIMARY KEY (PREFERENCE_ID, PREFERENCE_VALUE)
);
INSERT INTO PREFERENCE_ENTRY VALUES ('AAA-P1', 'TRUE');
INSERT INTO PREFERENCE_ENTRY VALUES ('AAA-P2', 'TRUE');
```

My SQL -

```
SELECT g.ID
FROM TEST_GROUP g 
JOIN GROUP_PREFERENCE gp ON g.ID = gp.GROUP_ID
JOIN PREFERENCE_ENTRY pe ON gp.ID = pe.PREFERENCE_ID
WHERE (
      (gp.TYPE = 'CONFIGURABLE' AND pe.PREFERENCE_VALUE = 'TRUE')
      AND
      (gp.TYPE = 'ENABLED' AND pe.PREFERENCE_VALUE = 'TRUE')
      )
```

I want the SQL to return the TEST_GROUP 'AAA' but it looks like because I am testing for both PREFERENCE_ENTRY values it doesn't.  If I test for either one on it's own it does return the row *but* I need to test that both PREFERENCE_ENTRY entries are 'TRUE'.

I'm sure this is quite simple but I'm struggling with it...

Any help from you SQL gurus will be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: gp.TYPE = 'CONFIGURABLE' and gp.TYPE = 'ENABLED' cannot be true at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  Oracle also has a nice shorthand for what you want to do using `in`:

```
SELECT g.ID
FROM TEST_GROUP g JOIN
     GROUP_PREFERENCE gp
     ON g.ID = gp.GROUP_ID JOIN
     PREFERENCE_ENTRY pe
     ON gp.ID = pe.PREFERENCE_ID
WHERE (gp.TYPE, pe.PREFERENCE_VALUE) IN ( ('CONFIGURABLE', 'TRUE'), ('ENABLED', 'TRUE') )
GROUP BY g.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gp.TYPE) = 2;
```

Comment: Could you explain a little as to why the HAVING is needed.  It seems to work without that?

Comment: Because you only want to see groups that contain both types.

Answer (score 2):

In Where conditions use OR not AND

```
(...)
WHERE (
      (gp.TYPE = 'CONFIGURABLE' AND pe.PREFERENCE_VALUE = 'TRUE')
      OR
      (gp.TYPE = 'ENABLED' AND pe.PREFERENCE_VALUE = 'TRUE')
      )
```

Edit:

```
SELECT g.ID
FROM TEST_GROUP g 
JOIN GROUP_PREFERENCE gp1 ON g.ID = gp1.GROUP_ID and gp1.TYPE='CONFIGURABLE'
JOIN GROUP_PREFERENCE gp2 ON g.ID = gp2.GROUP_ID and gp2.TYPE='ENABLED'
JOIN PREFERENCE_ENTRY pe1 ON gp1.ID = pe1.PREFERENCE_ID
JOIN PREFERENCE_ENTRY pe2 ON gp2.ID = pe2.PREFERENCE_ID
WHERE pe1.PREFERENCE_VALUE = 'TRUE' and pe2.PREFERENCE_VALUE = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: But I only want the row returned if *both* are true.

Comment: How can `gp.TYPE` equal two values?

Comment: Yes I know, that's the problem. But I only want 'AAA' returned if both 'preferences' are TRUE.

Comment: I already tried as you have suggested but to me it just didn't look right and so I thought I must be missing some more obvious way...?

Comment: i added second way

Comment: Don't use `CASE WHEN` in `WHERE`; use `AND` and `OR` instead. You will probably notice that your second query does not work. For the same reason that OP's query doesn't. A type cannot be 'CONFIGURABLE' and 'ENABLED'  at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, you have rigth

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option that may seem like the straight-forward approach.

You noticed that you cannot join the tables and then use the `WHERE` clause to check for 'CONFIGURABLE' and 'ENABLED', because the `WHERE` clause refers to one row and one row's type cannot be 'CONFIGURABLE' and 'ENABLED' at the same time.

What you would do instead is select from the main table and look up the other tables in the `WHERE` clause with `EXISTS` or `IN` (where `IN` is the simpler of the two).

```
select id
from test_group
where id in
(
  select gp.group_id
  from group_preference gp
  join preference_entry pe on gp.id = pe.preference_id
  where gp.type = 'CONFIGURABLE' and pe.preference_value = 'TRUE'
)
and id in
(
  select gp.group_id
  from group_preference gp
  join preference_entry pe on gp.id = pe.preference_id
  where gp.type = 'ENABLED' and pe.preference_value = 'TRUE'
);
```

Simply aggregating over `group_preference` and `preference_entry` as shown by Gordon is easier though and the preferred approach (you can remove the table `TEST_GROUP` from his query - it's not needed). But sometimes there is a situation where you need lookups with `EXISTS` or `IN` instead, so I thought I'd just mention the method :-)